# Check for input and sleep boost thread

Tags: c++, linux, boost, blocking, cin

I'm trying to build a thread that checks for user input and if the input equals "exit", it turns off all other threads.

The way that I use `cin` seems to stop the thread.  The thread should run, check for user input, and if there is any and it equals "exit", turn `runProcesses` off.

This is my code that doesn't work as expected as "newline stopped" never is printed, "running" is printed only once:

```
void check_for_cin() {
    while ( runProcesses ) {
        cout << "running";
        string input;
        std::getline( std::cin, input );
        //while ( std::getline( std::cin, input ) ) {
        if ( !input.empty() ) {
            if ( input == "exit" ) {
                runProcesses = false;
                cout << "exiting" << ", run processes: " << runProcesses;
            }
        }
        cout << "newline stopped";
        boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::seconds( 1 ) );
    }
    cout << "no longer checking for input";
}
```

How can my intent be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Asio's file descriptor service objects.

Posix has a 'reactor' style asynchrony, so you don't actually need threads to achieve asynchronicity.

My example shows a reading loop that exits when 'exit' is typed /or/ when a timeout expires (10s).

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/posix/stream_descriptor.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service my_io_service;
boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor in(my_io_service, ::dup(STDIN_FILENO));
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(my_io_service);

// handle timeout
void timeout_expired(boost::system::error_code ec) {
    if (!ec)
        std::cerr << "Timeout expired\n";
    else if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) // this error is reported on timer.cancel()
        std::cerr << "Leaving early :)\n";
    else 
        std::cerr << "Exiting for another reason: " << ec.message() << "\n";

    // stop the reading loop
    in.cancel();
    in.close();
}

// set timeout timer
void arm_timeout()
{
    timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
    timer.async_wait(timeout_expired);
}

// perform reading loop
void reading_loop()
{
    std::cerr << "(continueing input...)\n";
    static boost::asio::streambuf buffer; // todo some encapsulation :)

    async_read_until(in, buffer, '\n', [&](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::string line;
                std::istream is(&buffer);
                if (std::getline(is, line) && line == "exit")
                    ec = boost::asio::error::operation_aborted;
                else
                    reading_loop(); // continue
            } 

            if (ec)
            {
                std::cerr << "Exiting due to: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                // in this case, we don't want to wait until the timeout expires
                timer.cancel();
            }
    });
}

int main() {

    arm_timeout();
    reading_loop();

    my_io_service.run();
}
```

On windows, you can use the equivalent [Windows Stream Handle](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__stream_handle.html)

You could trivially add threads by running `my_io_service.run()` on more than one thread.

Comment: The loop is already there. `my_io_service.run()` and `void reading_loop()` makes sure it is only exited when 'exit' was entered on stdin (I added the timeout as a simulation of 'other work', but you are free to [leave it away](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6964311/)

Comment: No need to be so timid! Boost Asio represents a radically different approach to program flow.  It takes getting used to.